# TypeScript complaining when using more than one selector

Tags: typescript

I'm using the following function to search HTML elements by text:

```
function findElementsByText(text: string): HTMLElement[] {
  const selectors = 'button'
  // without this, when `text` is empty, all the elements on the page will match
  const pattern = new RegExp(text === '' ? '^$' : text)

  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selectors)).filter(
    (element) => element.innerText.match(pattern)
  )
}
```

I don't want to only search buttons, so I added anchor tags:

```
  const selectors = 'a, button'
```

But, strangely, now I get this TypeScript error:

> Type 'Element[]' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement[]'.
> Type 'Element' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 116 more.

Why did adding one more selector cause this, and how to remove the error?

Live code:

[image: Edit TypeScript selectors]

Comment: TS is able to make type inferences based on CSS queries, though its handling seems a bit basic, so since TS can't handle your query it uses the most basic possible type that `querySelectorAll` can return, which is `Element[]`. Anyway you can fix the error (and improve your code) by just removing the return type annotation on your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is smart enough that it can recognise that the string "button" will give a NodeList of `HTMLButtonElements` elements (you can tell by hovering over `querySelectorAll` in the link you provided).

Here is the type definition for it:

> ```
> querySelectorAll<K extends keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): NodeListOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]>;
> querySelectorAll<K extends keyof SVGElementTagNameMap>(selectors: K): NodeListOf<SVGElementTagNameMap[K]>;
> querySelectorAll<E extends Element = Element>(selectors: string): NodeListOf<E>;
> ```

`"button"` and `"a"` are listed in `HTMLElementTagNameMap`…

> ```
> interface HTMLElementTagNameMap {
>     "a": HTMLAnchorElement;
>     "abbr": HTMLElement;
> ```

…  so the first definition matches and it returns `NodeListOf<HTMLElementTagNameMap[K]>`

Once you change the selector to something more complex, it doesn't match anything (because it compares the *whole string*, it can't parse it at this point) so it falls back to the last definition which returns
`NodeListOf<E>` where `E` has just been defined as something that extends `Element`.

Since the elements might be from a non-HTML source, it can't be `HTMLElement`, hence the error.

The simple workaround is to use a generic type to override that:

```
querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(selectors)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code did work, because `querySelector` has an overload which returns `HTMLButtonElement` list

```
function findElementsByText(text: string): HTMLElement[] {
  const selectors = 'button'
  // without this, when `text` is empty, all the elements on the page will match
  const pattern = new RegExp(text === '' ? '^$' : text)

  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selectors)).filter(
    //                       ^?
    // (method) ParentNode.querySelectorAll<"button">(selectors: "button"): NodeListOf<HTMLButtonElement> (+2 overloads)
    (element) => element.innerText.match(pattern)
  )
}
```

If your selector is not a single tag name, you need to use `as HTMLElement[]` or provide generic type

```
function findElementsByText2(text: string): HTMLElement[] {
  const selectors = 'button, a'
  // without this, when `text` is empty, all the elements on the page will match
  const pattern = new RegExp(text === '' ? '^$' : text)

  //                                          vvvvvvvvvvv
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>(selectors)).filter(
    (element) => element.innerText.match(pattern)
  )
}
```